# HotSpot security implementation

Tags: security, wifi

In our testing environnment, we use openwrt running wifidog client and gateway, we can not make the access point part of the DMZ nor use VLAN isolation on the productions sites.
Say the access point is 192.168.0.253 and the gateway/dns is 192.168.0.254, does putting a /30 subnet mask to the wired interface of the AP would provide a secure isolation of the acess point (the AP does packet filtering as well)?
Any recommandations for this setup are welcome.
So by the way if you have deployed an opensource solution for a Hotspots network, what did you choose and why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested coova but it doesn't suit our needs very well mainly for the Radius accounting part. Thanks for your answer.

We finally opted to wire the AP to the DMZ, but it seems that as long as no one breaks in the AP, the netmask isolation tip is ok.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http://coova.org/ for wifi management software.

Access points will vary very wildly, you will have to check for theri documents.